# How to load balance multiple node single kafka consumer app?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, load-balancing, spring-cloud

I have a spring boot Kafka listener which listens to single topic and consumer List. Now This spring boot app is now having 3 nodes. Now I need to make sure that number of List message is load balanced evenly to all 3 nodes.
How can I achieve this in my application?

Answer (score 0):

In Consumer, **group.id** (ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG) config provides balancing of the load. Each record published to a topic is delivered to one consumer instance within each subscribing consumer group.

[group.id][1]:

> A unique string that identifies the consumer group this consumer
> belongs to. This property is required if the consumer uses either the
> group management functionality by using subscribe(topic) or the
> Kafka-based offset management strategy.

```java
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
    import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
    import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
    import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer;
    import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;
    
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    
    @Configuration
    public class KafkaConsumerConfiguration {
    
    
        private Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
            final Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "your brokers");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "consumeer-group-id");
            return props;
        }
    
        @Bean
        public ConsumerFactory<String, YourClass> kafkaListenerConsumerFactory() {
            final ErrorHandlingDeserializer<YourClass> errorHandlingDeserializer = new ErrorHandlingDeserializer<>(new JsonDeserializer<>(YourClass.class, false));
            return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(this.consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(), errorHandlingDeserializer);
        }
    
    
        @Bean
        public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, YourClass> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
            final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, YourClass> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
            factory.setConsumerFactory(this.kafkaListenerConsumerFactory());
            return factory;
        }
    
    }


  [1]: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_group.id
```

Comment: The problem here is I want to distribute the load based on the List size message that is being consumed. Let's say Node1 consumes message with list of size 100 and then next kafka message comes with List of size 1 and is consumed by Node 2. So you see here the difference is huge. I want to balance this load based on the size of kafka message.